# How to load a cross-domain JSON with $http in angularjs 1.0.8 as it does with 1.2.0

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http-headers, cross-domain

Using Angular 1.0.8 I was trying to load a [JSON](http://www.json-generator.com/j/cdnueRTRmG) from a server that doesn't support get OPTIONS, and consequently got a error.

[Demo for 1.0.8](http://embed.plnkr.co/INCgwIrHKK3peuxjQXH9/preview)

```
OPTIONS http://www.json-generator.com/j/cdnueRTRmG 405 (Method Not Allowed)
OPTIONS http://www.json-generator.com/j/cdnueRTRmG Origin http://run.plnkr.co is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.json-generator.com/j/cdnueRTRmG. Origin http://run.plnkr.co is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I've tried to update angular to 1.2.0-RC and the error is gone.

[Demo for 1.2.0](http://embed.plnkr.co/NdvfTmxcum6lCuTpqaas/preview)

This is exactly the same code, a fork that loads the new version of angular, in fact the code is almost the same you can find in [$http angularjs docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http).

**How can I fix the this problem using the v1.0.8?**

I've read some hints about [removing the headers from the request](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1454) but couldn't make this work over the sample code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

I added that line before the call to $http and it worked in your 1.0.8 plunker.

Comment: The json-generator stuff backing that plunkr probably expired or was removed. The technique is still valid. Thanks for the downvote!

Comment: you should remove the plunkr link as it does not exist anymore.

Comment: @aet I'm having this same issue (client / api communication works when hosted on same server, but not cross domain) and this method causes a different error: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.2/$injector/modulerr?p0=testApp&p1=TypeErro…%20at%20Gd%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5001%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A1)