# Making a POST request with Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Caveat: I am a front-end developer, I don't have much experience with servers.

I'm building an app with Angular 1.2 that pings an API on a different subdomain. The backend dev on the project is using nginx and has set it up to allow cross-domain requests by essentially forwarding the subdomain, or something similar, I believe.  I can do an `$http.get` request just fine, but when I try `$http.post` I get the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error.

Here's the kicker: I can make the same request with jQuery's `$.ajax` and it works just fine.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://api.mydomain.com/v1/customer/',
    data: theData,
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    //contentType: 'text/plain',
    //crossDomain: true,
    success: function(){
        console.log("sent data via jquery");
    }
});
```

Here's how I have Angular set up:

```
var myServices = angular.module("myServices", []);

myServices.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
});
```

And:

```
    save: function(payload){
        console.dir($http);
        return $http.post('http://api.mydomain.com/v1/customer/', payload).then(function(result){
            return result;
        });
    },
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661032/http-get-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-but-ajax-is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here:

http://victorblog.com/2012/12/20/make-angularjs-http-service-behave-like-jquery-ajax/

Angular sends serialized JSON, jQuery sends a query string.

Comment: Then you should accept your own answer, so that another people would find a solution quickly in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty close, I see you're using `.then()`, so just follow the promise return pattern and pick it up in your controller:

```
return $http.post('http://api.mydomain.com/v1/customer/', payload).then(function(result){
    return result.data;
});
```

And your controller (I dont know what your service is called, replace `TestService` with the name):

```
TestService.save(param).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data); //Hello data!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a CORS related problem, specifically with the X-Requested-With header.
See this post:
[How to load a cross-domain JSON with $http in angularjs 1.0.8 as it does with 1.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905912/how-to-load-a-cross-domain-json-with-http-in-angularjs-1-0-8-as-it-does-with-1)