# Cross-domain $http request with AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have a Java service running on my main OS(Windows7 Pro.) and I can access it throu broswer at `http://localhost:8080/...`. It returns valid JSON reposnse.

I also have a [SPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) written in `angularjs`, that is located on my virtual machine where I created a Virtual-Host for it(for more comfortable access). Virtual machine OS is Ubuntu Server 12.04.X LTS.

Since those environments are in network terms separated from each other, I was trying to access Java service through my local machine IP address `X.X.X.X:8080`(*pinging through terminal did send response*). Since normal `$http` usage didn't work I tried solution suggested in this answer [How to load a cross-domain JSON with $http in angularjs 1.0.8 as it does with 1.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905912/how-to-load-a-cross-domain-json-with-http-in-angularjs-1-0-8-as-it-does-with-1), but either it is too old or something else is wrong, but when I try to do same it just doesn't work. In console I see only following

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://X.X.X.X:8080/library/api/books. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://dev.xxx' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: You need to enable cross origin resource sharing (CORS) on your java service.

Comment: Tried to enable it as it is explained here http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-cors.html, but didn't help in anyway.

Comment: Make sure you have added the CORS interceptor to your jax-rs server.  CORS works if you follow the Apache CXF instructions to the letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for their input. Can't say was my solution correct or not, but I got result I was expection.

I combined info found here [`Filter requests for CORS`](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/#_filter_requests_for_cors) with answer from this question [Java / Jetty: How to Add Filter to Embedded Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530806/java-jetty-how-to-add-filter-to-embedded-jetty). I wasn't sure how to add a filter, that would listen for request and set response headers accordingly.

Hope that solution will help to those who might come in contact with same situation.